# Is there any way of shortening the loops in my code to speed up the Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the site and also new to writing VBA. I have made an attempt at the Macro and it does run successfully eventually. The problem arises with the speed of the macro; it is painfully slow even using it on one sheet. I need to replicate this across 10 sheets and run the macro on each! The issue appears to be with the For/Next loops, but I do not have the coding experience to resolve the speed issue. I have attached the VBA for inspection and any advise would be most welcome.

```
Sub Cloud_Sales()

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
Worksheets("Cloud Sales").Activate
With Sheets("Cloud Sales")

    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the N column
        With .Cells(LRow, "N")

           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Unsuccessful") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Unsuccessful"
                'in Column N.
            End If
        End With

    Next LRow

    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the N
        With .Cells(LRow, "N")

           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Not Evaluated") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Not Evaluated"
                'in Column N.
            End If
        End With

    Next LRow

    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the N
        With .Cells(LRow, "N")

           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Suspended") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Suspended"
                'in Column N.
            End If
        End With

    Next LRow

    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the L column
        With .Cells(LRow, "L")

           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("North America") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "North America"
                'in Column L.
            End If
        End With

    Next LRow

    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the L
        With .Cells(LRow, "L")

           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Latin America") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Latin America"
                'in Column L.
            End If
        End With

    Next LRow

    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

        'We check the values in the L
        With .Cells(LRow, "L")

           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("APJ") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "APJ"
                'in Column L.
            End If
        End With

    Next LRow

    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Chinese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Chinese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Japanese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Japanese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
      Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Korean") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Korean"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
      Next LRow


     For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - AM") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - AM"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - ILT") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - ILT"
                'in Column E.
            End If
         End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - LA") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - LA"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop Attendance Verification - APJ") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop Attendance Verification - APJ"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
    Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Chinese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Chinese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
    Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Japanese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Japanese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
    Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Korean") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Korean"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
    Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("VMAX 101 - Chinese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "VMAX 101 - Chinese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
    Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("VMAX 101 - Japanese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "VMAX 101 - Japanese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
    Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("VMAX 101 - Korean") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "VMAX 101 - Korean"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("XtremIO 101 - Chinese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "XtremIO 101 - Chinese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("XtremIO 101 - Japanese") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "XtremIO 101 - Japanese"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow


    For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        'We check the values in the E
        With .Cells(LRow, "E")
           If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If LCase(.Value) = LCase("XtremIO 101 - Korean") Then .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "XtremIO 101 - Korean"
                'in Column E.
            End If
        End With
     Next LRow

End With

'This will copy and paste Column E and insert into a new column P,maintaining header formatting
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("P:P").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Course Title]]").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("P1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


'This will change the multiple values for each Course Title to one specific title
        Set r = Range("P:P")
        mytext = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test"

For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - English" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - French" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - German" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Post-class Test - Russian" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        End If

    Next
        Set r = Range("P:P")
        mytext = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop"

For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - EM" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency 2016 Workshop - ILT" Then
        End If

    Next
        Set r = Range("P:P")
        mytext = "Sales Cloud Competency Prework"

For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - English" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - French" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - German" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Sales Cloud Competency Prework - Russian" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        End If

    Next
        Set r = Range("P:P")
        mytext = "VMAX 101"

For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "VMAX 101 - English" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "VMAX 101 - French" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "VMAX 101 - German" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "VMAX 101 - Russian" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        End If

    Next
        Set r = Range("P:P")
        mytext = "XtremIO 101"

For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "XtremIO 101 - English" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "XtremIO 101 - French" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "XtremIO 101 - German" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        ElseIf cell.Value = "XtremIO 101 - Russian" Then
            cell.Value = mytext
        End If

    Next

    'Remove duplicates from "Learner Email Address" & "Course Title2" columns
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 16), _
    Header:=xlYes

    'Resize Raw Data table to add in new Column P to table in order to refresh Pivot
    Worksheets("Cloud Sales").ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A:$P")

    'Hide Raw Data tab, open pivot table tab

        Worksheets("Cloud Sales").Visible = False
        Worksheets("Cloud Sales Pivot").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Cloud Sales Pivot").Activate

    ' Create Pivot Table
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Cloud Sales!R1C1:R1048576C16", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Cloud Sales Pivot!R2C2", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Cloud Sales Pivot").Select
    Cells(2, 2).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Course Title2")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "Learner Main Geography")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Learner Email Address" _
    )
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Course Title2"), "Count of Course Title2", xlCount

   'Inform the user that the process has successfully completed

      MsgBox "Cloud Sales Complete", vbOKOnly, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code is functioning, a better place to ask this question would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where they specifically focus on improving and optimizing working code

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly remember this for the future. I always try to complete the code myself first as experience of doing is a great teacher

Comment: Indeed it is!  I only pointed you there because those users may be better suited to help you with further optimization.  We are, of course, always happy to have a member like yourself join the SO community.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commented on your post to link you to codereview, a stack exchange site that is best for questions of this nature, but just from looking at your code, there are a few quick and easy optimizations you can make.  Any loop that is going through the same data (ie For each cell in r) does not need to be repeated.  For example, rather than using the same variable `mytext` three times, create three different `mytext#` variables and then use the If conditions appropriately.  That way your code only runs through the range once but makes all the appropriate changes.  The same can be done for every single one of your row deletions in the first section of the code.

I'll give one exmaple to make it clear how this can be improved, so the process should be simple enough to follow. Instead of:

```
For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

    'We check the values in the N column
    With .Cells(LRow, "N")

       If Not IsError(.Value) Then
            If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Unsuccessful") Then .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "Unsuccessful"
            'in Column N.
        End If
    End With

Next LRow

For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

    'We check the values in the N
    With .Cells(LRow, "N")

       If Not IsError(.Value) Then
            If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Not Evaluated") Then .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "Not Evaluated"
            'in Column N.
        End If
    End With

Next LRow

For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

    'We check the values in the N
    With .Cells(LRow, "N")

       If Not IsError(.Value) Then
            If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Suspended") Then .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "Suspended"
            'in Column N.
        End If
    End With

Next LRow
```

Combine the conditions into a single loop, like this:

```
For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
     With .Cells(LRow, "N")
       If Not IsError(.Value) Then
            If LCase(.Value) = LCase("Suspended") Then 
            .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "Suspended"
            'in Column N.
            ElseIf LCase(.Value) = LCase("Not Evaluated") Then
             .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "Not Evaluated"
            'in Column N.
            ElseIf LCase(.Value) = LCase("Unsuccessful") Then 
            .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "Unsuccessful"
            'in Column N.
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next LRow
```

Do this in each of your loops and your code should run much much faster

You can also shorten with "Select Case ", like this:

Combine the conditions into a single loop, like this:

```
For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
    With .Cells(LRow, "N")
       If Not IsError(.Value) Then
           Select Case LCase(.Value)
               Case LCase("Suspended")
                   .EntireRow.Delete
                'This will delete each row with the Value "Suspended"
                'in Column N.
               Case LCase("Not Evaluated")
                   .EntireRow.Delete
                   'This will delete each row with the Value "Not Evaluated"
                   'in Column N.
               Case LCase("Unsuccessful") 
                   .EntireRow.Delete
                   'This will delete each row with the Value "Unsuccessful"
                   'in Column N.
           End Select
        End If
    End With
Next LRow
```

Or even if all cases have the same procedure, you can use:

```
For LRow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
    With .Cells(LRow, "N")
       If Not IsError(.Value) Then
           Select Case LCase(.Value)
               Case LCase("Suspended"), LCase("Not Evaluated"), LCase("Unsuccessful")       
                   .EntireRow.Delete
                   'This will delete each row with the Value "Suspended"
                   'in Column N.
            End Select
        End If
    End With
Next LRow
```

Do this in each of your loops and your code should run much much faster

Comment: I left the `If-ElseIf` structure even though the command is the same because (as far as I'm aware) there is no performance improvement by placing all of the statements in one logical check with OR statements between them, but its possible that that could also improve speed.  The `If-Elseif` is just much easier to read with as many conditions as you have

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply, I will attempt to implement your recommendations and come back with feedback. Thanks again

Comment: @Mullak5 look at the edit I made, you can also use the `Select Case` statement to shorten your code.

Comment: @ShaiRado  Good suggestion.  I don't believe this has an affect on the runtime, but its a functional alternative (and the second select case is a much cleaner way to write it all)

Comment: @Mullak5 have the suggested edits resulted in the time improvement you desire?

Comment: Many thanks RGA, much improved performance and the code is much cleaner. Appreciate the advice and assistance

Comment: @Shai Rado. Thanks for the extra suggestions, I intend to copy my file and implement your Select Case ideas. I will run both files separately and compare runtimes. Thanks

Comment: @Mullak5 Let us know the results! I'm curious to see if there is a quanitifiable difference between the two methods